# Using a timer in conjunction with two push buttons from Arduino input

Tags: unity, timer

noob here

So I am using two push buttons (connected to an Arduino Uno) as an input to my game. The player has to push down both buttons at the same time for the character to move in the game. I want the player to hold down the buttons for a different amount of time in each level. I have a working Arduino and a working Unity timer and player script, but am not able to get the code to do what I want. What I basically want is that only when the player presses the buttons down, does the timer start counting down. Right now, the timer starts as soon as the scene begins. I know that I somehow have to reference the timer script to the button object, I have tried this but it still doesn't work. Note that the timer UI does have a Timer tag on it. I have also referenced the Player Controller script in the Timer script. Right now, the timer just doesn't count down at all. Please help
Please assist in any manner

The Timer script:

```
   using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    //int startTime = 0;
    public bool buttonPressed = false;
    public int timeLeft;
    public Text countdownText;
    GameObject Character;
    void Awake()
    {
        Character = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    public void Start()
    {
        //StartCoroutine("LoseTime");
        BeginTimer();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        countdownText.text = ("Time Left = " + timeLeft);

        if (timeLeft <= 0)
        {
            //StopCoroutine("LoseTime");
            //countdownText.text = "Times Up!";
            Invoke("ChangeLevel", 0.1f);
        }
       }
    public void BeginTimer()
    {

        Character.GetComponent<PlayerController>().Update();
        if (buttonPressed == true )
        {
            StartCoroutine("LoseTime");
        }
    }

IEnumerator LoseTime()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            timeLeft--;
        }

    }
    void ChangeLevel()
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

The Player controller script:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("\\\\.\\COM4", 9600);
    //player == GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<>();

    public float Speed;
    public Vector2 height;
    public float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
    public bool buttonPressed = false;
    GameObject Character;

    void Awake()
    {
        Character = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
    }
    void Start()
    {
        if (!sp.IsOpen)
        { // If the erial port is not open 
            sp.Open(); // Open 
        }
        sp.ReadTimeout = 1; // Timeout for reading
    }

    public void Update()
    {

        if (sp.IsOpen)
        { // Check to see if the serial port is open 
            try
            {

                string value = sp.ReadLine();//To("Button"); //Read the information
                int button = int.Parse(value);
                //float amount = float.Parse(value);
                //transform.Translate(Speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);  //walk


                if (button == 0) //*Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space*/)  //jump
                {
                    buttonPressed = true;

                    Character.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(height, ForceMode2D.Impulse);

                    Character.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position = new Vector3
                    (
                        Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position.x, xMin, xMax),
                        Mathf.Clamp(GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position.y, yMin, yMax)
                    );
                    Timer tmr = GameObject.Find("Timer").GetComponent<Timer>();
                        tmr.BeginTimer();


                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {


            }
        }
        void ApplicationQuit()
        {
            if (sp != null)
            {

                {
                    sp.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips and assistance will be appreciated

Comment: You said that you have a working timer script and working arduino, so what specifically is the issue you are encountering? What is desired behavior vs current behavior? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @disc_code22 So right now as soon as the scene starts, the timer begins counting down. So even if the player doesn't press the push buttons, the timer will start and once it reaches 0 will change to the next scene. So what I want is that only when the player presses the buttons, will the timer start and let's say the time for that level is 50 seconds, then the player has to hold the buttons down for 50 seconds for the character to move. So that's the issue that I am currently having

Comment: @disc_22 And then if the player releases the button before the time is over, the timer will reset and the player will have to start again with the original time

Comment: Right now the timer doesn't know anything about the ports or inputs and is just decrementing unconditionally. If you want the timer behavior controlled by the port inputs you need to implement that somewhere, either in the timer class, or in the player class, then communicate that to the timer. Eg: the "LoseTime" coroutine could check a boolean flag to see if the button is being held and only decrement the time if true. By toggling the flag based on the port inputs you can have the timer run only if certain inputs are held. Using a similar approach you can reset the timer value on input change

Comment: @disc_22 Thank you. I thought as much...that I would to reference the port input to the timer somehow. This is what I am struggling with: I don't really know how to do that. Think you could help me with that?

Comment: It seems like you are already getting the port inputs in the player class, so is your issue about how to get/observe/listen for a variable in another class? eg: you have input variable in Player and you want to take some action in Timer depending on the variable in Player? If so, you can find plenty of resources on this topic by searching for how to access/expose variables to another class in C#. The main techniques for communicating across classes include exposing the variable as public, making a public getter, or using events/messaging to alert listeners.

Comment: @disc_code22 Yes, the main issue is how to use or rather connect the fact that the button is being pressed to the Timer script. Okay, thank you I will look into that

Comment: @disc_code22 Hello, I have tried referencing the timer script in the player script but it still isn't working. The timer doesn't count down at all now. Could you please take a quick look?

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: @disc_code22 It isn't giving me an error.. that's why I dont know what is wrong

Comment: try adding some debug log statements at various points to determine where the code is executing and where it isnt. Alternatively debug the program line by line to see where it diverges from your expected behavior. Try adding a print statement inside the `if(sp.IsOpen)` block to see if the port is opened successfully.

Comment: @disc_22 okay I will do that, thanks. Though I don't think it's the port as I was using the port when the player script didnt reference the timer script and it worked there

Comment: @disc_code22 I haven't tried the debug log as yet, but from what I have been reading now(some other examples), I might have to reference the Player controller script in the timer script as well. I have tried this but it still isn't working as yet.  I have updated the code accordingly, I think the problem may be how I am referencing the update function in the Player controller script: Character.GetComponent<PlayerController>().Update();

Comment: as this post is less about game, i think asking it in stackoverflow can cause better results becasue you can find both arduino and unity programmers

Comment: @virtouso the question is regarding the confusion about referencing the timer script in another script attached to unity. But yes, I have also posted in on stackoverflow as well. Thank you